# Match elements between two lists, then use position of matches on third list

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension

I have two lists of the same length. One with integer values, and each values corresponding binary value. I need to match the integers to a third list, and then find the binary value that matches that integer.

```
binary  = read_dataset(itype, 'ExSitu')      #len(binary) = 195400
id      = read_dataset(itype, 'ParticleIDs') #len(id) = 195400

id2     = read_dataset(itype, 'To_Match')    #len(id2) = 19100
```

So I need to find every instance where a value from 'id2' is in 'id'
I've done this so far with:

```
set(id) & set(id2)
```

Which gives the values that match.
Now I need to use the positions of those values in 'id' to extract the binary values in 'binary'

For example, 'id' starts:

```
[183,739,172,384...]
```

In each position is a corresponding value in 'binary'

```
[0, 1, 1, 0,...]
```

I wish to gather and count the 1's and 0's in 'binary', but only in positions where integers in 'id' match integers in 'id2'.

So for 'id2' list of

```
[999, 998, 739, 997...]
```

Only one integer matches, with the corresponding value in 'binary' of 1.

I feel there's a way to do this through list comprehension, but I can't find the way to do it. Are you clever people able to help?

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: if you are interested in the binary values corresponding to your integers why you don't just do `binaries = [bin(elem) for elem in set(id) & set(id2)]`? Is there a reason to get the one in  `binary `?

Comment: Ah thanks, but I'm only interested in the binary values in positions of 'id' that match values from 'id2'. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Could you maybe show small example of input and corresponding output?

Comment: I have updated my question to include this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the binary values of the integers in both `id1` and `id2` you can do it as follows:

```
binary_vals = [bin(elem) for elem in set(id) & set(id2)]
```

It's not clear why you want the specific binary values of `binary`, but in that case what you can do is

```
binary_vals = [binary[id.index(elem)] for elem in set(id) & set(id2)]
```

**after update**

```
binary_vals = [binary[id.index(elem)] for elem in set(id) & set(id2)]
print("Zeros : {}, Ones : {}".format(binary_vals.count(0),binary_vals.count(1)))
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but it's not quite what I'm after. This is my fault for being unclear. The list 'binary' is a list of values that are either 1 or 0. I need to count the number of 1's and 0's that correspond to integers in the same list position as in the list 'id'. But only integers that are also in 'id2'.

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question with an input for binary, id1, and id2 and the expected output.

Comment: I've updated the answer according to the additional details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly - you want a list of positions of values in id2 which are present in id. For that you could do the below:-

```
want = [i for i,j in enumerate(id2) if j in id]
```